# VSCode: Python interpreter isn't being set

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have used pip within a venv to get the packages I need, and activated the venv after they've downloaded. Pip list shows the required packages as being installed, but when running the .py file in VSCode, I'm given an error message stating no package found. I've tried the following.

I'm all out of ideas and this is driving me bonkers.

- removing the venv and recreating it
- selecting the interpreter in VSCode (which does close to nothing I believe)
- restarting the language server (which fails everytime)
- setting the "python.defaultInterpreterPath" to my venv
- reloading window in VSCode
- restarting PC

EDIT:
[ErrorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gb3r8.png)

The correct python interpreter is listed in the status bar, I've tried swapping it to a different one and it doesn't seem to affect anything. I've also tried setting the interpreter in the command palette.

Comment: Include the exact (except for paths) error message.

Comment: is the Python interpreter listed in the status bar, you must let VSC activate the environment, what is the exact command used to execute the py file

Comment: VSC **NEVER** sets a Python interpreter automatic, YOU have to set it with the proper command, search for `python` in the palette